# Stop automatic scrolling on page content change

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a page which adds and removes some content to itself on a scroll event.

Now when using Chrome(IE11 doesn't seem to have this behaviour), whenever the content is added and removed to the page a scroll event is generated (I guess in order to keep the client view consistent on page changes).

I don't want this. The scroll event generated on the content change will trigger more content changes which will in turn trigger more scroll events.

Any advice on how I can stop this behaviour for all browsers? I don't want any automatic scrolling to happen. I only want user scrolling to be registered.

Here is some simple example code. Clicking the "click" button will reshuffle the colored diffs and make the page scroll by itself (in Chrome, not IE11)...

```js
function removeStuff(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("center");
    document.getElementById("container").removeChild(elem);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
#top {
    background-color: green;
    height:1500px;

}

#center {
    background-color: blue;
    height:1000px;
}

#bottom {
    background-color: red;
    height:1500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
  <button id="button" onclick="removeStuff()">click</button>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 29):

**This is a Chromium feature recently added, called scroll-anchoring.**

Disable in the browser: go to `chrome://flags/#enable-scroll-anchoring` and set "Scroll anchoring" to "Disabled".

Disable via CSS:

```
.some-element {
    overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

Comment: Useful note: this CSS property must be applied to the children of the scrollable element to prevent an unwanted scroll

Comment: The `overflow-anchor` property works only in Blink and Gecko but fortunately only Blink and Gecko have such scroll behavior

Comment: Big thanks... a note to anyone who stumbles upon this trying to find a fix for the annoying openHAB 1.8.3 web UI... This works... Just unzip the jar, and add *{ overflow...  to the openhab.css file. No more annoying jumps on DOM updates :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootrap 4/5, this is a resolve

```css
* {
    overflow-anchor: none !important;
    scroll-snap-stop: normal !important;
    overscroll-behavior: unset !important;
    scroll-behavior: unset !important;
}

.container, header, footer, .container-fluid, body, div, span, section {
    overflow-anchor: none !important;
    scroll-snap-stop: normal !important;
    overscroll-behavior: unset !important;
    scroll-behavior: unset !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disable this behavior, but you can work around it. Because Chrome does the `scroll` event synchronously when you call `removeChild`, you can detect these types of scroll events by setting a global boolean to `true` just before the `removeChild` and setting it back to `false` directly after.

```
var isRemovingStuff = false;
function removeStuff(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("center");

    // Chrome does a scroll here, set isRemovingStuff to true
    // so our scroll handler can know to ignore it.
    isRemovingStuff = true;
    document.getElementById("container").removeChild(elem);
    isRemovingStuff = false;

    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(elem);

   // TODO: set the scrollTop back to what you want it to be.
}
```

And your scroll handler would look like:

```
function onScroll() {
    if (isRemovingStuff)
        return;

    // Do cool stuff
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the event seems to be triggered after the function which alters the contents of the page finishes

Answer (score 0):

chrome auto scroll : enable / disable /// windows /ubuntu

[image: chrome auto scroll : enable / disable]

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
  overflow-anchor: none !important;
}
```

> The overflow-anchor CSS property provides a way to opt out of the browser's scroll anchoring behavior, which adjusts scroll position to minimize content shifts.
>
> Scroll anchoring behavior is enabled by default in any browser that supports it. Therefore, changing the value of this property is typically only required if you are experiencing problems with scroll anchoring in a document or part of a document and need to turn the behavior off.

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).