# Multiple ajax requests, how keep user looking at same div when page is scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The page has 3 inputs and 3 content areas. If a user enters a value into the last input, then all 3 content areas are updated and become bigger. However 2 of them are above the last input, causing the user to watch the content 'fly' past the screen.

How to keep the user looking at the same input, and then scroll gracefully to the last content area

Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kimit/7L08e0yz/30/):

```
<div id="content1">
  Content 1
</div>
<div id="content2">
  Content 2
</div>

<a href="#" id="videos-link"> CLICK HERE </a>
<div id="content3">
  Content 3
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#videos-link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#content3').html('loading');

    $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
      complete: function(response) {
        var height = (Math.random() * 1000) + 300;
        $('#content1').height(height);
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
      complete: function(response) {
        var height = (Math.random() * 1000) + 300;
        $('#content2').delay(200).height(height);
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
      complete: function(response) {
        var height = (Math.random() * 1000) + 300;
        $('#content3').html('loading').delay(500).height(height).html('finished loading');
        var offsetTop = jQuery("#content3").offset().top - 10;
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, 1000);

      }
    });


  });

});
```

In the fiddle, I would like the user to keep looking at the 'a' element, and then scroll gracefully to the content3 div when the ajax request is complete.

Comment: So your problem is that the scrolling beginning is messed up because it jumps to another place and then starts to scroll to element3?

Comment: Thats pretty much it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `content1` and `content2` expand everything is pushed down so it looks like you are scrolling up then scrolling down..

There is no actual solution to this, but as a workaround you can scroll to the 3rd `<a>` element every time you change the height of the divs before it in the DOM.

**Step 1:** 
Store the **relative** offset of your `<a>` tag

`var relative_offset = $('#videos-link').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();`

you will want to get this value before any ajax response so best place to define `relative_offset` in the begging of the click event.

**Step 2:**
Change the scroll

For both for the 1st and 2nd ajax responses you need to change the scrollTop of `window` to the `<a>` tag position - `relative_offset`:

```
//...
$('#content_x').height(height); // offset().op of <a> has changed 
$(window).scrollTop($('#videos-link').offset().top - relative_offset);
```

**Final Code**
I have not tested the but it should look something like this:

(i might have missed a `+` with a `-` somewhere but i believe that this is the current approach of solving the issue)

```
$('#videos-link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var relative_offset = $('#videos-link').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

  $('#content3').html('loading');

  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    complete: function(response) {
      var height = (Math.random() * 1000) + 300;
      $('#content1').height(height);
      $(window).scrollTop($('#videos-link').offset().top - relative_offset);
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    complete: function(response) {
      var height = (Math.random() * 1000) + 300;
      $('#content2').delay(200).height(height);
      $(window).delay(201).scrollTop($('#videos-link').offset().top - relative_offset); // i set delay to 201 just to be sure it runes after
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!',
    complete: function(response) {
      var height = (Math.random() * 1000) + 300;
      $('#content3').html('loading').delay(500).height(height).html('finished loading');
      var offsetTop = jQuery("#content3").offset().top - 10;
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
      }, 1000);

    }
  });


});
```

Related question: 
[Stop automatic scrolling on page content change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958463/stop-automatic-scrolling-on-page-content-change)