# Chrome scroll behavior when adding items to the DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

I am implementing an infinite scroll in order to display operations grouped by date. When the user reaches the bottom of the page, I load the next operations.

So, after scrolling a little, the user will see this :

```
-------------------------------------------
May, 23rd
  Operation 11
  Operation 12     This zone is visible
  Operation 13     by the user
  Operation 14
  Operation 15
  page bottom
-------------------------------------------
                    this zone is outside 
                    of the viewport
-------------------------------------------
```

As the bottom is reached, the new operations are loaded. The expected behavior is this :

```
-------------------------------------------
May, 23rd
  Operation 11
  Operation 12     This zone is visible
  Operation 13     by the user
  Operation 14
  Operation 15
-------------------------------------------
  Operation 16
  Operation 17
  Operation 18      this zone is outside 
  Operation 19      of the viewport
  Operation 20
  page bottom
 -------------------------------------------
```

The loading is transparent to the user. Scrolling can continue seamlessly.  The actual behavior, **in Chrome only** is that :

```
-------------------------------------------
  Operation 16
  Operation 17
  Operation 18      This zone is visible 
  Operation 19      by the user
  Operation 20
  page bottom
-------------------------------------------
                    this zone is outside 
                    of the viewport
-------------------------------------------
```

It seems that Chrome autoscrolls in order to keep the last element visible (here, the page bottom). This results in an infinite loading of next operations.

The data is a map `{[key: string]: Operation[]}` where `key` is a `date` represented as a `string`.

I render it like this :

```html
<section *ngFor="let entry of accountOperations | keyvalue:descOrder">
  <h3>{{entry.key}}</h3>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let operation of entry.value">
      <app-operation [operation]="operation">
      </app-operation>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**Question** : Is there a javascript function that I can call to deactivate this behavior ?

I prepared a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcwfsd) in order to reproduce the problem. Please try it **in Chrome**.

**Scenario** :

- Click 10 times on "Add a category to the map"
- Scroll to the bottom of the page
- Click 3 times again on "Add a category to the map"
- The page bottom remains visible. It should not.

Curiously, I don't reproduce the problem if I use a simple list with `*ngFor` (which you can test with the other button : "Add an item to the list")

Also, I don't have the problem if I remove the "Page Bottom" element. I suppose that in this case, Chrome will focus on the last element of the list.

Answer (score 4):

Some css on the child element fixed this issue for me.

In my case:

```
.load-more{
  overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

Answer taken from here:
[Stop automatic scrolling on page content change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958463/stop-automatic-scrolling-on-page-content-change)

Comment: if you are simply linking to an answer, just use the comments. if you are writing the whole answer code, then, its better to put it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up — as my account is new, I can't comment, it says I need to have a reputation of 50. Unsure what to do, but let me know if you think I should delete this answer.

Comment: jack, its alright. dont worry about it. leave the answer as it is. if it attracts too many negative votes, then, you may want to delete it. otherwise, leave it be for now.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer Jack! Somehow my Google query didn't lead me to that link, but led me to this question, and this simple one liner fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there isn't a simple way to just disable this behaviour. I think Chrome is trying to keep what is on screen static and avoid 'screen jump'. In many cases this is desirable, however obviously not in this case.

A workaround is to use a spacer element between the bottom of the dynamically loaded content and the page bottom element. This spacer has it's height adjusted in preparation for loading in the dynamically loaded content, this effectively creates a space for the new content to load and shifts the viewport away from the bottom of the content, stopping the behaviour you are observing.

You can see a rough proof of concept of this in my fork of your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4c8asn) .

For reference here are the key parts of the code.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  counter = 1;
  itemCounter = 1;
  loading = false;

  categories: { [key: string]: string[] } = {
    'category 1': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
  }

  items: string[] = [];

  addCategory() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.fetchCategory().then((category : string[]) =>{
      this.categories['category ' + this.counter++] = category;
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }

  addItem() {
    this.items.push('Item ' + this.itemCounter++);
  }

  fetchCategory() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      window.setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve(['A1','A2','A3']);
        this.loading = false;
      }, 300);
    });
  }

  descOrder = (a, b) => {
    if (+a.key.substring(9) < +b.key.substring(9)) {
      return b.key;
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button id="btn-add-category" (click)="addCategory()">Add a category to the map</button>
<button id="btn-add-item" (click)="addItem()">Add an item to the list</button>

<section *ngFor="let cat of categories | keyvalue:descOrder">
  {{cat.key}}
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let val of cat.value">{{val}}</li>
  </ul>
</section>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <h3>{{ item }}</h3>
  </li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="loading" class="loadingSpacer"></div>

<h1 id="page-bottom">Page bottom</h1>
```

And you add `height:100px;` or similar to the `loadingSpacer`.

Here I am incorporating a promise and an artificial delay to simulate loading. It may or may not be possible to do something like this in a synchronous fashion, but since it involves two operations (expand the height, load the content) which need to be reflected in the DOM / page state in a particular order my feeling is that it is inherently asynchronous.

I first considered using something like `window.scrollBy` instead of CSS and HTML, which would seem to be a more obvious solution. However I found that it would be tricky to use this while avoiding unsightly screen jumping or being dependent upon knowing the height of the content in advance.

I'm not 100% sure why this works at this point, as it was a pure experiment based upon the idea of 'is there some way that I can force the scroll up using CSS'. There would be some finessing to do and has some technical and design limitations, but should at least give you something to work with.